# References string parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, bibtex

I have many strings like this one. Is there are library in Python that can extract names, journal, dates, title, ...etc?

```
Wallace, Kelly. "Bush Stands Pat on Stem Cell Policy." CNN. 13 Aug. 2001.
```

I tried using pybtex, but doesn't return anything for string, it has to be in specific formats.

```
from pybtex.database import parse_file,parse_string
print(parse_string('Wallace, Kelly. "Bush Stands Pat on Stem Cell Policy." CNN. 13 Aug. 2001.','bibtex'))
# it returns nothing
BibliographyData(entries=OrderedCaseInsensitiveDict([]), preamble=[])
```

Comment: https://spacy.io/?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an NLP solution. Check out NLTK: https://www.nltk.org/

Without any fixed format, NLP is the way to go.